# Trying to assign a functions return value to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that checks whether the value of a selected element equals the span id. Everything works fine except for the variable assignment.
To be more precise: The function itself works (if i alert object.id it is displayed right) but the variable assignment doesn't. If I try to alert the variable, it says it's undefined. I'm sure it's some minor mistake and it would be very nice if someone could point it out:

```
var spanId = (function getId(object) 
    {   
    return object.id;
    //alert(object.id);
    })();
```

Comment: I don't understand how the alert can be correct. You aren't passing any arguments when you call the function, so you would be trying to alert `undefined.id` which would throw an exception.

Comment: strongly, strongly recommend K&R style brackets over GNU style brackets

Comment: How does `undefined` have an id when it works?

Comment: @Quentin <span id="2" onclick="getId(this);"> I didn't post the entire script.

Comment: You expect spanId to be updated when you call getId? That is not going to happen. That function has no relationship with that variable.

Comment: I expect the return value of the function to be assigned to the variable. Which should be the id of span.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote btw: Really encouraging. I'm a noob, I get it. But it is difficult to get any better with such a helpful and understanding community...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the variable will not update that variable when you call it again and again. You need to restructure your code in order to update that variable.

```
var spanId;
function getId(object) {   
    spanId = object.id;
};
```

now `spanId` will have the current value.